# I have some problems with random module, lists and converting some variables

Tags: python, list, variables, random

I started recently working with Pyton 3.10 and while I was creating a graph that works with random data I got a problem. I want the random module work between a minimum and a maximum value but the random value have to oscillate in a range between +- 0 to 0.10 compared to the previous value and so I had a problem to convert the list from the random.choices (named value) in a float number, i got this error "Expected type 'SupportsFloat | SupportsIndex | str | bytes | bytearray', got 'list[float]' instead" I know I can't convert a list in a float because a list is a set of numbers but searching on internet I found nothing to solve in others ways this problem. Can you please help me?

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

minimo = 90.00
massimo = 110.00
altissimo = 108
alto = 104
basso = 96
bassissimo = 92
x_vals = []
y_vals = []
pmin = ()
pmag = ()
valori = [minore, maggiore]
index = count()
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)


def animate(i):
    global minore
    global maggiore
    global pmin
    global pmag

    value = random.choices(valori, weights=[pmin, pmag])
    print(value)
    value = float(value)     #<-- here is the problem
    value = round(value, 2)

    if value > altissimo:
        pmin = 80
        pmag = 20
    elif alto < value < altissimo:
        pmin = 60
        pmag = 40
    elif basso < value < alto:
        pmin = 40
        pmag = 60
    elif bassissimo < value < basso:
        pmin = 20
        pmag = 80

    delta = random.uniform(0, 0.10)
    delta = round(delta, 2)
    minore = value - delta
    maggiore = delta + value

    print(value)
    x_vals.append(next(index))
    y_vals.append(value)
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
    plt.tight_layout()


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental misunderstanding, I think, is in this line:

```
valori = [minore, maggiore]
```

You seem to be expecting that `random.choices` will use that to choose between the current values of `minore` and `maggiore`.  That's not how Python works.  What that statement does is grab the current VALUE of those two variables.  If you change `minore` after that, the `valori` list will not change.

I believe you are just using that array to choose whether to start with the `minore` or `maggiore` value, based on the percentages in `pmin` and `pmag`.  There is an easier way to do that, just by checking whether `random.random()` produces a number above or below that.

And please eliminate all the calls to "round".  Rounding is only to be used when you are presenting numbers for human consumption.  Let the computer work with all the significant digits it can.  Remember that "0.20" is still an approximation; it cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Part of your problem is the numbers you were using for your categories.  Your aim is to have the value hover around 100, but with your ranges, anything between 96 and 104 will trend downward (40% chance of going up), so the graph always goes down.  You need to have the center range use a 50% value.

Your 90 and 110 values may be a guideline, but they aren't used for anything, and I've removed them.

This does what I think you want, but I hope you realize stocks don't actually behave this way.  They don't tend to gather around a midpoint.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

altissimo = 108
alto = 104
basso = 96
bassissimo = 92
x_vals = []
y_vals = []
pmin = 0.50
index = count()
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
value = 100.0


def animate(i):
    global value

    if value > altissimo:
        pmin = .90
    elif value > alto:
        pmin = .70
    elif value > basso:
        pmin = .50
    elif value > bassissimo:
        pmin = .30
    else:
        pmin = .10

    sign = 1 if random.random() < pmin else -1
    value += sign * random.uniform(0, 0.10)

    print(value)
    x_vals.append(next(index))
    y_vals.append(value)
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the program works but not in the way I wanted. Let me explain, I'm tring to simulate stock market trend so I set a max value in this case 110 $ and a min 90 $ (maggiore and minore), these two values are the maximum and the minimum price inside of the market oscillates and I need it to be random so it will be unpredictable, however I need this to oscillate, so when the price goes very high (altissimo) there is a higher probability that it goes down and so on. At the same time I need the variation to be little this is why I set delta between 0 and 0.10.

Comment: See if you like this better.  This does hover around 100.

Comment: I changed some values, now it works as I want, thanks for all, here is the modified code.                                                                                                                                     
        if value > altissimo:
        pmin = .90
    elif value > alto:
        pmin = .70
    elif value < basso:
        pmin = .70
    elif value < bassissimo:
        pmin = .90
    else:
        pmin = .50

Answer (score 0):

random.choices always returns a list.  If you call it with the default `k=1`, it returns a **list** of 1 value.  You could fix this in a couple of ways.

1. On the line you marked as a problem, replace `value = float(value)` with `value = float(value[0])`
2. Change the line where you call random.choices to: `[value] = random.choices(valori, weights=[pmin, pmag])`.  That means that you expect random.choices to return a list of 1 item, and that you want to put that item (not the list) into the variable 'value'.